# Check if score is equal to the last score checked, and if it is, put both of them in the same rank from a dict

Tags: python

I need to check if the score is equal to the previous one, if it is, change both to the same one.
But I can't figure out how. I have included the file and the json file
I have also removed a few functions that i think are unnecessary, but if you want to see it it is
https://github.com/IdkDwij/PLTW-CSP-1.2.2/tree/main

```
import json

b_s = 15
s_s = 20
g_s = 25


#return the leaderboard dict
def getLeaderBoard():
  with open('plist.json', 'r') as f:
    myDict = json.loads(f.read())
  return myDict


def checkTie():
  myDict = getLeaderBoard()
  index = 0
  for x in myDict["score"]:
    pass
    # I need to check if the score is equal to the previous one, if it is, change both to the same one
```

```
{
    "rank": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ],
    "name": [
        "Floppa the fish",
        "Dwij",
        "mat",
        "yes",
        "Mathew"
    ],
    "score": [
        11,
        9,
        8,
        8,
        1
    ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output in this example?

Comment: can you add more detail about what you want to do if equal to the pervious one?

Comment: side comment: don't [write the data back to the original file](https://github.com/IdkDwij/PLTW-CSP-1.2.2/blob/main/lb.py#L46) while testing, if you have any bugs it will just erase your test data, write to a new file and then see if it is behaving correctly.

Comment: mkrieger and abdullah, I want it to say

Comment: this is an example
1. Floppa the fish: 13
2. Dwij: 8
2. Mathew: 8
3. Jack: 5
4. Noah: 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really quite simple:

```py
def checkTie():
  leaderboard = getLeaderBoard()
  lastScore = -1
  rank = 0
  for x in enumerate(leaderboard["score"]):
    if lastScore != leaderboard["score"][x]:
      rank += 1
    leaderboard["rank"][x] = rank
    lastScore = leaderboard["score"]
  return leaderboard
```

Comment: It threw an error

Comment: File "main.py", line 84, in countdown
    lb.sortLeaderBoard(player_name, score)
  File "/home/runner/pltw-122/lb.py", line 28, in sortLeaderBoard
    checkTie()
  File "/home/runner/pltw-122/lb.py", line 36, in checkTie
    if lastScore != leaderboard["score"][x]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Before I fix the problem, could you specify the desired return value? Would you like the function to return a leaderboard where they are ranked according to score? Or would you only like to detect changes? I need some context.

Comment: this is an example 1. Floppa the fish: 13 2. Dwij: 8 2. Mathew: 8 3. Jack: 5 4. Noah: 2

Comment: There can only be 5 scores, but 2 even scores need to have the same rank

Comment: It still throws a TypeError "if lastScore != leaderboard["score"][x]. list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple""

Comment: When you iterate through an enumerate object, [you get tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate). Maybe (not sure what you want) it could be `if lastScore != leaderboard["score"][x][0]`?